# What do I add in the .gitignore of a console application with kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, console-application, gitignore

I want to upload a console project made in kotlin to my repository on GitHub, but I don't know which files should go in the .gitignore

I searched the internet for files to put, but I have nothing clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to [gitignore.io](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/) from Toptal, where a `.gitignore` generated for you, based on your input.

If you write *Kotlin* in the input-field, or some more/others, it will generate a `.gitignore` with the specific files, which are ignored in this programming language, ide, tool…

By pressing the "Create" button, it create the `.gitignore` file, as requested.

As example, a `.gitignore` file with only *Kotlin* as argument, will look like:

```
# Created by https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/kotlin
# Edit at https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore?templates=kotlin

### Kotlin ###
# Compiled class file
*.class

# Log file
*.log

# BlueJ files
*.ctxt

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.nar
*.ear
*.zip
*.tar.gz
*.rar

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*
replay_pid*

# End of https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/kotlin
```